# Grandchildren and Great-grandchildren of a process

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I am trying to get the grandchildren and grand grandchildren PID'S of a certain PID that I pass as an argument.

So, I am trying to find the simplest solution possible for a beginner.
Now, I used `pgrep -P $pid`, to find the children of a certain PID, but now that I want to go even deeper, I think I might need to use a data pipe and filter out more stuff out of it.

```
pgrep -P $pid | grep something
```

but how do I go deeper into the descendent of these children? is there a way to reuse the `pgrep -P` once again, but this time on the result I got?

**P.S**

I researched in this forum before about this, but all solutions are quite advanced for me and I don't really understand them.
Would even love to know if possible to have a solution only using `ps -P` without the pgrep.

Comment: so `pstree $pid`?

Comment: @KamilCuk that gives me the entire tree, but how do I extract the grandchildren and grandgrandchildren out of it? would need to grep, correct?

Comment: Then you'll have to do it yourself. Get all children of PID, iterate over them, for each get children, iterate over them, for each get children and print only those from level 2 and 3. `would need to grep, correct?` Sure, you could parse the output of `pstree`.

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67668/elegantly-get-list-of-descendant-processes)

Comment: Why do you need those specific descendants? Usually, you care about child processes because you need to wait on them, but you can't wait on the children of your children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily using [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

`pgrep -P $pid | xargs -n1 pgrep -P`

that would give you the grandchildren. `xargs` will take the output of the first command and pass it one by one (`-n1`) to the second command

using only ps:

`ps --ppid $pid -o pid --no-headers | xargs -n1 ps --no-headers --ppid`

Comment: Aha, so by doing:
`pgrep -P $pid | xargs -n1 pgrep -P | xargs -n1 pgrep -P`
I can also get the grand-grandchildren ?

Comment: Thank's alot! thats the kind of solution I was looking for, and well explained :)!